# What do we call a program on TV that is for education?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Some TV programs are primarily intended for advertising, some for entertainment, ..., and some are primarily intended for education, for example, to teach people scientific facts about the world. What is a good word for such programs? Educational programs?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62456/discussion-on-question-by-sasan-what-do-we-call-a-program-on-tv-that-is-for-educ).

Answer (score 3):

TV programs which "teach people scientific facts about the world" are typically *popular* science programs and are called ***infotainment*** (sometimes also called *edutainment* as mentioned in another answer already).
They are designed to be entertaining at the same time to sustain the interest of the laypeople (in the context of the specific program) in contrast to AV media content specifically meant to teach experts or students (in that or related field).

ODO:

> **[infotainment](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/infotainment)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> Broadcast material which is intended both to entertain and to inform.
>
> ‘In TV, we've seen the growth of infotainment formats blending
>   entertainment and informational aspects of media consumption.’

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the common term is ***educational programming*** or ***educational shows***. In cases where the presentation is equally focussed on education and entertainment, you may see the term ***edutainment*** (which is <s>not actually a word, but rather</s> a neologism (coinage) assembled from ***edu***cation and *enter**tainment***).

Comment: So such a program is call "educational programming" or "educational program" ?

Comment: An individual program would be an ***educational program*** or an ***educational show***; collectively, a group of ***educational programs*** or ***educational shows***, or the concept itself, can be called ***educational programming***.